# how to setTimeout within a function before navigating to other tab

Tags: javascript

I want to set a specific time out before the function navigates to another tab.

```
somefunc: function() {
    PageFrame.goToTab('test', function(item) {
        if(!item.search){

            return false;
        }
        //else do some stuff
    }, this);
}
```

The issue is when the `PageFrame.goToTab` is called to redirect to the "#test" page, the test page hasnt completely loaded then, hence I get a  undefined on `item.search`, though it loads after the error has been thrown. Hence I want to add a timeout for the function to wait until the page loads and then check for this condition: `if(!item.search){}`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: a timeout to wait for a page to load is not best practice - better to use events

Comment: Fix `goToTab` so it doesn't call the callback until after it has loaded the tab.

Comment: @Barmar:not a good idea to change the goToTab as it is a global method used by multiple apps

Comment: @Jaromanda X : do u have an ex?

Comment: Then maybe you should be using some other method. The point is that there should be some method that loads the data dynamically, and it should take a callback, and that's where you can access `item.search`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jaromand X said you should use an event that will tell you when the page has fully loaded instead just setting a timeout. From [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) *"The onload property of the GlobalEventHandlers mixin is an event handler for the load event of a Window, XMLHttpRequest,  element, etc., which fires when the resource has loaded."*

That means that once the content of the window has finished loading the onload event will be fired.

To use such event you will have to assing and 'event handler' this is a function that runs whe the event fires.

In your case you should do this:

```
function somefunc() {
    PageFrame.goToTab('test', function(item) {
        if(!item.search){

        return false;
        }
        //else do some stuff
    }, this);
}

window.onload = somefunc;
```

So you 'somefunc' will run when onload event fires. You don't write window.onload = somefunc(); because what you assign as event handler is a pointer to your function.

Comment: but this does not set any delayed time before the func is executed..not sure how the window.onload will help me to load the page completeley before executing the condition

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
somefunc: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
           PageFrame.goToTab('test', function(item) {
           if(!item.search){

               return false;
           }
           //else do some stuff
       }, this);
    }, 5000);
}
```